# Find Where a File was Requested from in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, embedded-resource

In preferably Google Chrome, is there a way to view which file/piece of code called for a specific resource?

I am trying to find where the file `http://thevideos.tv/embed-f6ze1qjbt3qr-728x410.html` is requested from on the url `http://putlocker.is/watch-three-amigos-online-free-putlocker.html`. I think they might have done some encryption in Javascript but I am not too sure.

Comment: Try the Initiator column on the Network tab of Developer Tools

Comment: Musa, if you want to add that as an answer that would be awesome for other people who may have this issue... That is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Initiator column on the Network tab of Developer Tools, if you hover over an item a popup shows you the trace of the scripts that initiated the request.

[image]